# Pyinstaller with Django: ModuleNotFoundError: No Module Named django.contrib.messages.apps

Tags: python, django, pyinstaller

I'm trying to run my packaged python application in the cmd line, and I get the error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No Module Named 'django.contrib.messages.apps'`

I used the answer from https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2332 to get rid of the similar error for `'django.contrib.admin.apps'`, so does anyone know how to remove this one as well?

Comment: Which Django version that you use? is your project running in a virtual environment? if yes, is it active?

Comment: @Lemayzeur Django version 2.0.4, yes it's running in a virtual environment

Comment: uninstall django, and re install it again

Comment: @Lemayzeur I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem with `Django 2.0.4`. Seems like it does not supports latest versions of Django. The problem is that PyInstaller can't resolve hidden imports, so you have to add them to hooks manually. Edit `.spec` file, which is created after first build with `pyinstaller`, fill array of `hidden_imports` with missing packages and make build pointing `.spec` file instead of `manage.py`. Unfortunelly, after adding few packages, new errors appears.

*https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html*

`Pyinstaller` works fine with **Django 1.8**, so try using this version. Project based on Django 1.8 builds successfully, and runs well using `runserver`

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked perfectly on Django 1.8.19

Comment: I had the same problem. As of Feb2019, I only got Pyinstaller v3.4 working when using Django 1.8, not with any higher version of Django. In case it matters, I used Python 3.5